# Publish my new NEOS backend plugin in the Neos official site

Tags: neoscms

I want to publish my newly created package to Neos official site's package list page.

https://www.neos.io/download-and-extend/packages.html

Actually, I do not know how to publish my newly created package. Please explain the steps to publish my custom package to the below url in the Neos site.

https://www.neos.io/download-and-extend/packages.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I got the answer from NEOS CMS official forum.The answer is mentioned below.

> The list is created from packagist. So register your package there. I
>   don't know how often the sync task is running.

https://discuss.neos.io/t/publish-my-new-neos-backend-plugin-in-the-neos-official-site/1760